# How to execute a remote bash script from PHP

Tags: php, node.js, bash, ssh

I need to execute a `bash script` on a remote web server from `PHP`. The request originates from `web1` via PHP and needs to execute a bash script on another web server `web2`. `web1` can SSH into `web2` all local traffic, but doing SSH via PHP is really nasty, and running `exec("ssh user@web2.mydomain.com ./bash_script")` seems like a terrible idea for security. Also, trying to expose some sort of HTTP interface from a bash script seems like the wrong approach.

What is recommended? Are there any cross language and remote execution libraries or frameworks?

Thinking I could write a simple wrapper in Node.js that executes the bash script and lives on `web2`. `web1` simply hits the node.js wrapper over HTTP.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe the latter is a better option.

Comment: Why not just have web1 contact web2 at a php file that executes the bash_script? Web2 can verify that it is web1 via IP.

Comment: @DaveChen PHP `exec()` is blocking, if I use node.js I can fork each request to run a separate thread of the bash script.

Comment: exec doesn't have to block, dun remember how, but there is a way to make it not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rexec` command for this. `rexec` will help you to execute a remote command.

```
rexec [ -abcdhns -l username -p password ] host command
```

See [this](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_rexec.htm) for more details.

Comment: Does `rexec` use SSH? I don't follow how the servers communicate? Is there a daemon I have to install on `web2`?

Comment: `rexec` is a linux command and it does not use SSH. I used the same command in my network servers to schedule backup jobs. I really don know how `rexec` works. One dis-advantage is that, your username and password send through as a plain text over network.